# Como mostrará el valor seleccionado (SELECTED) en CodeIgniter 3.x?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estoy tratando de rellenar una lista desplegable de la base de datos. En mi archivo de vista tengo el siguiente código

Aquí está mi controlador

```
//consulta los datos
$query = $this->interprete_model->interpreteID($this->session->userdata('user_id'));

print_r($query); // Usar print_r() para imprimir el arreglo; 

$data['interprete'] = $query;
```

Aqui esta mi vista, usa set_select.

```
<select class="form-control" name="regionI" id="regionI">
 <option value="">- Seleccione -</option>                                       
  <?php foreach($result_region as $region):?>
    <option value="<?php echo $region->id_region;?>" 
    <?php echo set_select('regionI', $region->id_region, TRUE); ?>><?php echo $region->nombre_region;?></option>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchos selected, necesito uno selected para modifica(update) los datos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deberías quitar `<?php echo set_select('regionI', $region->id_region, TRUE);` para que no devuelva todos los `option` seleccionados, si quieres que solo uno tenga el selected deberías agregar una condición con `if` como por ejemplo si la `$region` es 1 lo muestre seleccionado:

```
<select class="form-control" name="regionI" id="regionI">
 <option value="">- Seleccione -</option>                                       
  <?php foreach($result_region as $region):?>
    <option value="<?php echo $region->id_region;?>" 
    <?php 
       if( $region == 1 )
         echo set_select('regionI', $region->id_region, TRUE);?>>

<?php echo $region->nombre_region;?></option>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Espero resuelva la duda, saludos.